# Loop through string, remove commas, add to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm a little stuck on trying to figure this one out, I think I understand the principles but just a little lost on the execution.  Say we have:

```
$string = "Blue, Red, Yellow";
```

Which is a string read in from a DB (it includes the commas).  Basically what I'm trying to do break these words apart and store them separately in an array (easier to work with).  Will something like this work:

```
$string_parts = explode(",",$string);
```

Is it as easy as this, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's as easy as that. Do a `print_r( $string_parts );` to see the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to have spaces in the resulting array, add a space to the separator:

```
$string_parts = explode(", ", $string);
```

Note that this database design violates the [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 1):

If it works, then it's as easy as that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree with

```
$string_parts = explode(",",$string);
```

Afterwards, I would go through each element and trim off whitespace.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($string_parts); $i++)
    $string_parts[$i] = trim($string_parts[$i];
```

EDIT:
Instead of going through a for-loop and trimming off whitespace, I'd suggest

```
$string = str_replace(" ", "", $string);
```

then exploding the string.

Comment: Better to add the space in the separator as phihag said.

Comment: I'd agree with that if the assumption is that the DB string parts will always be separated by a comma and a space. Mine would take longer to execute in that regard. However, mine will work if there is not always whitespace after a comma ("Blue, Green,Red").

Comment: In that case it might be better to use regex split with an optional whitespace character

Comment: Actually, probably even better would be to str_replace whitespace, then exploding.

Comment: Yea, the string will always contain commas.  I appreciate the feedback guys, should be good to go.